# Robotium Tests gone wrong Android

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I tried a simple code for testing a simple Android App using the following code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv11g.png

I am getting Errors. I am unable to find out the reason. I have added Jar and added Javadoc address in right bar as well.
Also I need to know where can I find complete tutorial on Robotium for Android Testing.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Robotium NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875029/android-robotium-noclassdeffounderror)

Answer (score 0):

http://gyazo.com/46690b862b2bb29d0984a7f64d660552  =>your log message indicates that you've not included Solo jar => 
what you need is:
to import the jar into the libs directory of the test project and then adding it to the Build Path Libraries:

```
TestProject Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libreries -> Add JARs... -> TestProject/libs/robotium-solo-3.1.jar
```

**OR**

You will need to export the Robotium jar by going to Properties-> Java Build Path -> Order and Export. Then check the Robotium jar file.

Like on this image:
[image]

Hope this helps you.